# Calling REST request and handling REST response

Tags: jquery, rest, blockchain, hyperledger

Rest Request

```
POST host:port/chaincode

    {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "method": "deploy",
      "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID":{
            "path":"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"
        },
        "ctorMsg": {
            "function":"init",
            "args":["a", "1000", "b", "2000"]
        }
      },
      "id": 1
    }
```

Rest Response

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "status": "OK",
        "message": "52b0d803fc395b5e34d8d4a7cd69fb6aa00099b8fabed83504ac1c5d61a425aca5b3ad3bf96643ea4fdaac132c417c37b00f88fa800de7ece387d008a76d3586"
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

I have this set of request and response, and they mention that the interface port is 5000. How do I call this rest request and alert the response result? I tried jquery but I couldn't do it. They kept prompting me window error.

This is what I've tried doing

```
$.post('localhost:5000/chaincode', {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "method": "deploy",
                "params": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "chaincodeID": {
                        "path": "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"
                    },
                    "ctorMsg": {
                        "function": "init",
                        "args": ["a", "1000", "b", "2000"]
                    }
                },
                "id": 1
            }, function (serverResponse) {

                alert(serverResponse);
                //do what you want with server response

            })
```

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks quite good.

The only possible problem I see in sending the request is that the service might not run on your localhost.

The result is - as per specification - an object. Since `alert()` will only print `[object]`, it would be better to use `console.log()` for debug output.

Comment: I tried and they're returning me an error `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) chaincode(0,0)"` How do I check if my localhost:5000 is running or not? @joachimschirrmacher

Comment: The text `chaincode(0,0)` indicates that there is in fact a service listening on your localhost:5000. Status 404 however says that some resource cannot be found. It seems you want to use a Hyperledger fabric blockchain service, right? Then the `path` in your `chainCodeID` field should contain the path of your `chaincode_finished.go` file.

Comment: In fact `github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02` doesn't exist. I suppose you copied it from somewhere but it was only an example, which you need to adapt to your own requirements.

Comment: Might be that you only need to add the protocol to the URL in your parameter: `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02`

Comment: btw. https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode seems to be a nice tutorial to follow

Comment: Is this not a valid link? [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02)

Comment: Yes this seems to be a valid link, but it contains `https://` at the beginning, your `"path"` attribute doesn't.